# Is there a filter called 'network_admin_init'?

Tags: filters, actions, network-admin

Is there a network equivalent to 'admin_init', or what do I have to do to add an action to network admin screens? I use 'admin_init' for an action on admin network screens, but the respective function is not executed. Thank you!

Edit: Here's what I want to do. The respective plugin writes custom database tables and should therefore only by activated on a per-site basis in a network.

```
function no_network_activation() {
    // echo 'test1 ';
    if ( is_network_admin() &&  isset($_GET['no-network-activation']) ) {
        // echo 'test2';
        add_action( 'network_admin_notices', 'no_network_activation_notice' );

        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); 

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
            unset( $_GET['activate'] );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'no_network_activation' );

function no_network_activation_notice(){
    // Echo an admin notice: no network activation possible
}

function myplugin_database_adder($networkwide) {
    // Redirect to network plugin url and add param to show the attempt of network-wide plugin activation
    if (is_multisite() && $networkwide) {
        header( 'Location: ' . network_admin_url( 'plugins.php?no-network-activation=true' ) );
        exit;
    }
    else {
        // Add the plugin database tables
        // [...] 
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_database_adder' );
```

Comment: What are you hooking into `admin_init` that's not working?

Comment: Rereading the question few more times, I wonder if I misunderstood it the first time :-) Is the callback not running on network sites, or do you need to restrict  your code to network pages? @joschi81

Comment: @JacobPeattie: I will show this in an edit of my question.

Comment: @birgire: It seems to me that the code is not running on network admin pages (network plugin page). See the edit of my question to understand what I want to do.

Comment: try to start with nothing but echo in callback and build on top of that to make sure it runs on every page

Comment: Thank you. I had already done that, see the echos added yo the code. test1 is echoed in the admin plugins section of single sites in the network, but not on the network admin plugins page. test2 is never being echoed then (of course).

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict your `admin_init` callback with e.g. a [`is_network_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_network_admin/) check.